# Android build fail 'failed to run ant version'

Tags: android, bash, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to use ionic cordova to run the sample demo but there is an error when I try to build:

```
    Famtop myApp $ ionic build android
Running command: "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" c:\Users\Famtop\myApp\hooks\
after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js c:/Users/Famtop/myApp
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" c:\Users\Famtop\myApp\hooks\
after_prepare\020_remove_sass_from_platforms.js c:/Users/Famtop/myApp
Running command: c:\Users\Famtop\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat
c:\Users\Famtop\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Failed to run "ant -version", make sure you have ant installed and added
to your PATH.
    at c:\Users\Famtop\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:43:27
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1080:5)
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: c:\Users\Famtop\myApp\platforms\andr
oid\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: c:\Users\Famtop\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed
 with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (c:\Users\Famtop\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1080:5)
```

I have looked at similar questions that suggest I check the path but I am unsure how to do this: I have the latest JDK and Android suite.

Any help greatly appreciated.

F

Comment: I dont understand why this question is down voted? Its been viewed over a 1000 time and has a clear correct answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to download [ANT from this link](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)

then extract it, keep it in some folder. Then add variable in your system variable with name `ANT_HOME`

For example

```
Variable= `ANT_HOME` value= `H:\apache-ant-1.9.3`
```

Then add this to path variable

```
%ANT_HOME%\bin;
```

Comment: So there is a system variable now: ANT_HOME C:{path} but I am unsure what else to do.

Comment: when I type echo %ANT_HOME% in commandline I get: apache-ant-1.9.4

Comment: Thank yo that is working correctly now. I was making a mistake when inputing the path.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu users it is simple enough, do

sudo apt-get install ant

and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

In Window 8 .. once you set these PATHs you may need to reboot before phonegap/cordova/ionic can see the variables.     OR  If you set them in the command prompt you can use them right away.     I found this out the hard way that it doesn't work like it did in  Windows 7.  Just setting it in control panel is not enough.

Comment: it sounds more like a comment under the question, than the full scale answer on the question.